# Reply programmatically to WhatsApp notification

Tags: android

I wrote the below receiver [based on my understandinf of https://medium.com/@polidea/how-to-respond-to-any-messaging-notification-on-android-7befa483e2d7] to read and respond to WhatsApp incoming messages:

```kotlin
class NotificationListener : NotificationListenerService() {
    private var context: Context? = null
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = applicationContext
        lateinit var actions: StatusBarNotification
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn)
        val packageName = sbn.packageName
        var nTicker = ""
        if (sbn.notification.tickerText != null) {
            nTicker = sbn.notification.tickerText.toString()
        }
        val extras = sbn.notification.extras
        val title = extras.getString("android.title")
        val text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString()
        // val id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.BADGE_ICON_SMALL.toString()) /* .EXTRA_SMALL_ICON */
        val id = sbn.notification.getLargeIcon() //   .largeIcon;
        Log.i("Package", packageName)
        Log.i("Ticker", nTicker)
        if (title != null) {
            Log.i("Title", title)
        }
        Log.i("Text", text)
        val msgInfo = Intent("Msg")
        msgInfo.putExtra("package", packageName)
        msgInfo.putExtra("nTicker", nTicker)
        msgInfo.putExtra("title", title)
        msgInfo.putExtra("text", text)

        when (packageName) {
             "com.whatsapp"-> {
                 if (title != null) {
                     if (title.contains("Hasan Yousef"))
                         if (nTicker.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                             Log.i("Group msg", "yes")
                         } else {
                             Log.i("Group msg", "no")

                          //   var actions = sbn.notification.actions
                             val actions: List<android.app.Notification.Action> = sbn.notification.actions.toList()
                             lateinit var remoteInputs: Array<android.app.RemoteInput>
                             for (action in actions) {
                                 if (action?.remoteInputs != null) {
                                     remoteInputs = action.remoteInputs
                                    }
                             }

                             var bundle = sbn.notification.extras
                             var pendingIntent = sbn.notification.contentIntent

                             val localIntent = Intent()
                             val addFlags = localIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

                             remoteInputs.forEach { remoteInput ->
                                 bundle.putCharSequence(remoteInput.resultKey, "our reply")
                             }
                         }
                 }
                }

            else -> Unit 
        }

        if (id != null) {
            val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            // id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            val byteArray = stream.toByteArray()
            msgInfo.putExtra("icon", byteArray)
        }
    }

    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn)
    }
}
```

But upon running, it fails with error:

```sh
 java.lang.NullPointerException: sbn.notification.actions must not be null
```

And sometimes I'm getting:

```sh
E/on.notificatio: open libmigui.so failed! dlopen - dlopen failed: library "libmigui.so" not found
D/DecorView[]: onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.LeakedClosableViolation: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks. Callsite: close
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidCloseGuardReporter.report(StrictMode.java:1992)
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.warnIfOpen(CloseGuard.java:347)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixSecureDirectoryStream.finalize(UnixSecureDirectoryStream.java:580)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:291)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:278)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
W/System.err: StrictMode VmPolicy violation with POLICY_DEATH; shutting down.
```

Comment: Hi, as a author of this article - it seems like actions in this notification are null, it might be the case WhatsApp gave up on adding Wear actions to their notifications. 
I didn't use this functionality in last years to provide more data tbh

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your issue but here is a sample code. Hope this helps

[NotificationReply](https://github.com/fbiego/NotificationReply)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it and confirm you back.